# How to show cellWidget of QTableWidget only when clicking?

Tags: qt, qt5

I don't want all cellWidgets to show all the time. I want them only to show when user double clicks the cell.

Comment: you can inherit QItemDelegate for it

Answer (score 0):

When you add a widget to the cell hide it immediately [hide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#hide)

after user double clicks the cell use [cellDoubleClicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellDoubleClicked) signal to [show](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#show) cell widget